# How to fix a Visual Studio Code timeline stuck in the past?

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, timeline

## VSCode's timeline does not work in some of the files

My VSCode's Timeline does not record versions of JSONC and JSON files when the Save button clicked, which never happened before. However, some of them can be recorded normally.

I have checked out the settings file and the files were not added to the exclude list. The `settings.json` file itself can actually be normally recorded.

No matter what I change, the timeline still end months ago. The target files contains the plots of a developing story game.

Edit:

I have found out the problem. Actually it was because the file is too big. But how to configure the size limit of the timeline?